# Bootstrap: How to obtain plain border in input field?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps3331333/8o0my6c0/) I have an input field, with top and left borders in grey instead of orange (note that the border color is orange). I removed the shadow (in case the grey borders are inner shadows) but that didn't solve the problem. How to get a border that is completely orange?

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="Some value">
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"] {
  border-width: 4px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-color: orange;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `border-style` to `solid`. Currently it is `inset`.

And to be perfectly clear, this has nothing to do with Bootstrap, I don't see any Bootstrap styles affecting the border style. Rather where this gets set to `inset` is the browser's own default styles, seen as "user agent stylesheet" in the developer tools.

An example of all possible border styles, courtesy of [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp):

```css
p.dotted {border-style: dotted;}
p.dashed {border-style: dashed;}
p.solid {border-style: solid;}
p.double {border-style: double;}
p.groove {border-style: groove;}
p.ridge {border-style: ridge;}
p.inset {border-style: inset;}
p.outset {border-style: outset;}
p.none {border-style: none;}
p.hidden {border-style: hidden;}
p.mix {border-style: dotted dashed solid double;}
```

```html
<p class="dotted">A dotted border.</p>
<p class="dashed">A dashed border.</p>
<p class="solid">A solid border.</p>
<p class="double">A double border.</p>
<p class="groove">A groove border.</p>
<p class="ridge">A ridge border.</p>
<p class="inset">An inset border.</p>
<p class="outset">An outset border.</p>
<p class="none">No border.</p>
<p class="hidden">A hidden border.</p>
<p class="mix">A mixed border.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
input[type="text"] {
  border: 4px solid orange;
  margin: 20px;
  border-color: orange;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing `border-color` to `border` and have `#px solid orange`, but that's probably not what you're quite looking for. The orange border problem could just be a browser error. I see a full orange border when on Windows Chrome but not on Mac Chrome.